# How to serialize and deserialize tabcontrol c#

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, tabcontrol

I am using a tabcontrol which I want to serialize and save . I am using this code but it gives that tabcontrol class is not marked as serializable . How to mark it serializable as I am not able to override the class . How to do it ?

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.dat", FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    bin.Serialize(stream,tabControl1);
}
```

It gives this error

> System.Windows.Forms.TabControl not marked as serializable

Comment: You can't serialize the UI. You need to serialize your *data*. Unfortunately, winforms does not encourage proper separation between UI and data, therefore all sorts of bad practices (like trying to serialize the UI) go rampant. I suggest you read up about separation of concerns and databinding.

Comment: The UI it self is my data . The controls in tabpages are the data what to do ?

Comment: `The UI its self is my data` - no it's not.

Comment: TabControl is serialized every day of the week, just not in the way you like it.  The designer does it, it generates code.  Or you wrote your own code to fill the tab pages.  All you have to do is run that code again and you get the same TabControl back.  Exactly how you get that code to run again is entirely up to you, there is no one single correct answer.  new Form1() is certainly the simplest way.

Comment: @HighCore the controls in tabcontrol are is my data what to do ?

Comment: @HansPassant `Or you wrote your own code to fill the tab pages` - Or the user did it thru the GUI, in which case your reasoning falls apart and the UI **cannot** be serialized. You should encourage people into good practices instead of trying to bend concepts backwards (such as changing the meaning of the word "serialize") in order to justify bad practices.

Comment: @phpnet please, understand. UI IS NOT DATA. Therefore you cannot serialize the UI. If you need to serialize your *data*, then I suggest you extract your data from the UI using whatever mechanism you like (DataBinding would be much preferred) into a proper, strongly typed data model and use .Net's built in serializers to turn that model instance into a string. .Net is not PHP, I'm sorry.

Comment: I got your piont @HighCore , the mechanism can be to access the control list and then serialize it . But the problem is nothing in tab control gives the access for serialize

Answer (score 3):

## Why don't serialize Controls and is there an alternative?

If you serialize a control, there are some problems:

1. You can't do it because `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` not marked as serializable like you have seen.
2. If you will do it and only if it is allowed, are there a lot of properties and classes, interfaces, events etc. that are serialized with it, inherited from the classes above and that is not what you will.

   [image]

The only way you could do it is by made a new class, bind all the values you will save with the properties and serialize that class.

```
[Serializable] // don't forget this! It will mark your class so you can serialize it.
public class BindingClass // p.s.: give this a better name!
{
    public string Text { get; set; } // Bind whit a control of your tab control.
    public float Number { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; } // used for the image
    public IEnumerable<object> ListOfString { get; set; } // used for a list
}
```

## Code example

### Text and numbers

Well for text and numbers it is easy. You can made an intense of your class and you can bind that. After it you can serialize it. An example:

```
BindingClass bc = new BindingClass();
bc.Text = textBox1.Text;
bc.Number = numbericUpDown.Value;

using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.dat", FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    bin.Serialize(stream, bc);
}
```

### Images

For images is it a little bit complex. You can serialize an image but it is also a bad thing to do that. Better is to save the image in your `bin/debug` folder of your project and serialize the path of that image. An example:

```
string imageLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\myImage.jpg"
pictureBox1.Image.Save(imageLocation, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// declare bc like code above.
bc.ImageLocation = imageLocation;

// serialize bc.
```

If the image already exists in the file, you can override it. But if you will work with histories, not a good thing... You can solve it by use the current date time as filename! Change your code with this:

```
string imageLocation = Application.StartupPath +
                       DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg"
```

**Note:** You can also use a [blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) service like [Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/azure/dd135733.aspx) and [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) *(not free)* or upload images to [Imgur](http://api.imgur.com/), [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) or 9gag *(patical free)*. Remark that there must be an internet connection between the client and server. You can upload by searching on [Google](https://www.google.com) how to do it.

### List of string

For list of strings you can use this:

```
bc.ListOfString = comboBox1.Items;
```

## Note

I haven't test the code. So if you have a problem with one the examples comment it and I will look at it, but try also to look on Google for a solution for your problem. Try it yourself, best way to learn...

## Alternative for serialize <sup>(update 16-Jun-16)</sup>

Serializing is a save way to make your code unreadable for people. However that can give problems if you scale your application. The problem is also happen by Microsoft Word. The old `.doc` files are also serialized code, the new `.docx` files are zipped xml files and now it's easier to make `.docx` files.

Good alternatives are [Json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Comment: Of course this is wrong. You can't serialize any class if the base class (or any class in it's type hierarchy) isn't serializable. Please delete your answer immediately.

Comment: When I try to change it in desinger it gives MyTabControl not found in Forms , what to do

Comment: @phpnet: It was indeed a wrong way I have suggested you, what highcode has sayed. Here is a better way.

Comment: Changed my downvote for an upvote. This is indeed correct.

Comment: @Hein I am not able to get . With making this new serializable class how will I put the properties from my current tabcontrol into this ? I need to serialize the tab control on which the user will draw something( picturebox , command button etc) . Plz can u tell me about this ? in your example

Comment: @phpnet: the code for that is literally right there in the answer, in the second block of code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend serializing to the application startup path. Once deployed, that path is likely to be read-only. Use a temporary file instead.